# How do I serve Kinto via https from a docker container?

Tags: https, docker, kinto

As written in the Kinto docs, I can [specify a custom configuration](https://kinto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/get-started.html#custom-configuration) this way:

`docker run --env-file ./kinto.env -p 8888:8888 kinto/kinto-server`.

Also, it seems I can [suggest an http scheme](https://kinto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/production.html#recommended-settings) using the `http_scheme` property.

Now, if I:

1. Put `KINTO_HTTP_SCHEME=https` in the `kinto.env` file;
2. Run Kinto via the command above, and;
3. Go to https://example.com:8888/v1/;

I get a blank page.

### Additional Info

If I navigate to http://example.com:8888/v1/ instead, I get the usual JSON config stamped on the page. This JSON also contains a `url` property
which is https://example.com:8888/v1/ (and not http://example.com:8888/v1/), so something seems to be happening: the `.env` file is read. The link is clickable, but if I click it I still get a blank page.

Is this a bug? How do I fix this?

---

### Notes

It is important because Chrome won't allow me to serve http content if the page is served via https. It completely blocks out the request, showing an appropriate error in the console: `d Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.com:8888/v1/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Kinto says: `Fetch API cannot load http://example.com:8888/v1/. Failed to start.
Error: HTTP 0; TypeError: Failed to fetch(…)`

Comment: Can you check that your reverse proxy is configured to support https (certificate setup and so on)?

Comment: Chrome shows the green lock when I connect to the server but I'm using nodejs + express to serve my resources. I thought, maybe naively, that Kinto could handle HTTPS on its own. There is not much written in the docs in this regard. Anyway, given that I'm just one man handling the whole app, is there some way I could start exposing kinto on HTTPS without ramping up too many horses?

Comment: Like, for now, I just need it to work as soon as possible to start prototyping.

Comment: Kinto (and servers in general) doesn't provide you with an SSL certificate offhand. 

It can be configured to be served over TLS/HTTPS, but it will not serve the certificates itself.

If you want to access to your service via TLS, you should configure your reverse proxy to do it for you: it is not the responsability of Kinto to do it for you.

Comment: With ExpressJS I don't use any reverse proxy. I just configure the server passing in the certificate and I'm good to go. If I understand correctly, I can't do that with Kinto, I *have* to have a reverse proxy. Is that correct? If it's so that would answer my question. I'll look into that. Just tell me of I got it this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you run Kinto. `pserve` uses the waitress server by default, which doesn't have any HTTPS suppport.

Alternative servers can be used as a replacement (gunicorn or uwsgi for instance) as a replacement for pserve, by specifying it in the .ini file.

Here are pointers to the proper documentation:

- gunicorn: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=ssl#ssl
- uwsgi: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HTTPS.html

For instance, with unicorn it would look like this:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 5900
workers = 1
worker_class = gevent
```

And then configure gevent to do the SSL:

```
certfile=~/ssl/server.crt
keyfile=~/ssl/server.key
ssl_version=3
```

For uwsgi, you have a default configuration in the documentation, seehttp://kinto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/production.html?highlight=uwsgi#running-with-uwsgi

Hope that helps.

Or, you can use NGINX or haproxy to do the SSL termination for you.

Comment: You're talking about the .ini file that is generated by the `kinto init` command? Could you show me what options I should edit to have the server changed?

Comment: Also, since I had node.js already running on the server, I took inspiration from the comments from you and @NiKo on the question thread yesterday and made a reverse proxy that listens on httpS://example.com:8889, serving http://example.com:8888 where Kinto is running. Now all I have to do is to hide the insecure Kinto from the outside world and make it so that it only communicates to my proxy, so that all users will have to connect via httpS. Is there some Kinto (waitress) settings I could use to achieve this?

Comment: See http://kinto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/settings.html#scheme-host-and-port with the variables `kinto.http_host` and `kinto.http_port` which should solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Never used Kinto, but from the [documentation](http://kinto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/settings.html):

> The environment variables are exactly the same as the settings, but they > are capitalised and . are replaced by _.
>
> For example, kinto.storage_backend is read from environment variable KINTO_STORAGE_BACKEND if defined.

So, the [environment variable](http://kinto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/settings.html#scheme-host-and-port) you want to set in your `kinto.env` file is `KINTO_HTTP_SCHEME`, rather than `HTTP_SCHEME`.

Comment: I tried that, I also tried setting both `KINTO_VARIABLE` and `VARIABLE` but it's the same. It seems like they're both taken into account. In this case they both don't work.

Comment: I've just edited the question according to this answer so to not have the same reply all over again.